# Create a function for File.separator using Pattern Matcher

Tags: java, regex, separator

A static analysis tool when running on my java project gives "Portability Flaw In File Separator" error and I need to fix it. In my code, I have fileUnsafe. I want to use a method to convert it into fileSafe (explained below).

```
// Case 1
//no platform independence, good for Unix systems
File fileUnsafe = new File("tmp/abc.txt");

//platform independent and safe to use across Unix and Windows
File fileSafe = new File("tmp"+File.separator+"abc.txt");
```

Similarly for paths like -

```
// Case 2
//no platform independence, good for Unix systems
File fileUnsafe = new File("/tmp/abc.txt");

// platform independent and safe to use across Unix and Windows
File fileSafe = new File(File.separator+"tmp"+File.separator+"abc.txt");
```

I have multiple of these file addresses throughout my project and I need to create some conversion method that could just take in this path as a string, append File.separator to it, and return it. Something like this -

```
File fileSafe = new File(someConversionMethod("/tmp/abc.txt"));
```

I tried this method but it gives me NullPointerException on case 2.

```
public static String someConversionMethod(String target) {
        Pattern ptr = Pattern.compile("[\\\\\\\\|/]+");
        Matcher mtr = ptr.matcher(target);
        return mtr.replaceAll(File.separator + "" + File.separator);
    }
```

Any help either fixing this method or suggesting a graceful way to handle this situation would be appreciated.

nit - I referred to [Replacing character with File.separator using java.regex Pattern Matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767456/replacing-character-with-file-separator-using-java-regex-pattern-matcher) but it didn't really help my case.

Comment: I am not sure if we even need this method, because if you just use / everywhere, Java will operate correctly on all platforms. There should not be a need to use backslashes in Java filenames.
If that's the case, then why do we even need File. separator anymore?

Comment: which is the IDE that you use for Java programming? does it support Regex Find and Replace?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. It supports Regex Find and Replace.

Comment: Ignore the warning. It's wrong. `/` is a platform-independent path separator in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I would try splitting the string at the file separator into an array like so.

```
String str = "/tmp/abc.txt";
String result = "";
String rgx = "\\\\|/";
String [] arrOfStr = str.split(rgx);;
```

Then you can add your `File.separator` back in using a for loop. Like this:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < arrOfStr.length ; i++)
        result += File.separator + arrOfStr[i];
```

I start from index one because the first slash gets doubled in the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a one time change, you could use the regex find and replace in Eclipse

For the first case:
use Regex: `^File\sfileUnsafe\s=\snew File\(\"(?<folder1>[^\/]+)\/(?<fileName>[^\.]+)(?<extension>\.\w{3})\"\);`

Replace with: `File fileSafe = new File("${folder1}"+File.separator+"${fileName}${extension}");`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7C2QRY/1)

For the second case:
use Regex: `^File\sfileUnsafe\s=\snew File\(\"\/(?<folder1>[^\/]+)\/(?<fileName>[^\.]+)(?<extension>\.\w{3})\"\);`

Replace with: `File fileSafe = new File(File.separator+"${folder1}"+File.separator+"${fileName}${extension}");`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FBIPs6/1)

if you have more than one folder, you could continue this pattern and fix them.

I admit, this is not a clean straight forward way, but will get the job done.